# How to escape dot (.) character in a column name in document type orientDB?

Tags: escaping, orientdb, orientdb-2.1, database, nosql

I'm using orientDB 2.1.12, i have a requirement to create a column name with dot (.) in it, on a schemaless class.

I've tried:

```
insert into someClass set \`this.is.a.dot` = someValue

insert into someClass set this\`.\`is\`.\`a\`.\`dot = someValue

insert into someClass set this.is.a.dot = someValue
```

Nothing works.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible doing that.